# How to control two operations for same url in Spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Consider the following problem.

The user has chosen to create a document by clicking on the Create document and then he writes data into the document. The url for creating the document is /document/save.

For the subsequent write up, the existing document must be saved instead of creating a new one.

Here is my code for that.

```
@Controller
public MyController implements Controller, TemplateTypeAware
{
         @RequestMapping("/document/save")
         public String saveOrCreateDocument(@ModelAttribute DocumentWrapper wrapper, ModelAndView m)
         {
               if(m.getModel().get("document_id")==null)
               {
               Document doc=createDocument(wrapper);
               m.addObject("document_id",doc.getId());
               }
               else
               {
               saveDocument(m.getModel().get("document_id"), wrapper);
               }
          return documentView;
         }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="document_id" th:value="*{document_id}"/>
<!-- other fields -->
</form>
```

The problem here is, I am getting `document_id` always `null`. Is there any work around for this problem?

Thanks in advance. Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Why would it be anything other than `null`? If you're sending a request for an existing document, you need to identify that document in your request.

Comment: Are you sending the document_id as a request parameter?

Comment: When first time the page is accessed, creation must be done, so there would be no `document_id`, for subsequent saves, I have added the `document_id` model as object. When I set that object, I am returning the view which would something as in the updated question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, to make sure that I identify it as an existing document, I have added the generated document id to the request by adding Object and then using the `<input type="hidden">` I have put that value. Initially, the value would be null (which means to create new document), save otherwise.

Comment: Can you verify in debugger that `m.addObject("document_id",doc.getId());` is called and `doc.getId()` contains the value that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Form fields will be automatically bound to your `DocumentWrapper` fields if they have matching names, that means `DocumentWrapper` needs a field named *document_id*, otherwise the *document_id* request parameter won't be bound to your object.

Model attributes will be exposed to the view, at this point the model will be empty, you can add attributes in your handler method and they will become in your view, but request parameters won't be in the model. That explains why you always get null.

If you just need the *document_id* parameter, use `@RequestParam`:

```
@RequestMapping("/document/save")
public String saveOrCreateDocument(@RequestParam("document_id") Long documentId, Model m) {
...
}
```

Please refer to the binding section of Spring MVC: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: But while creating document, there will be no `documentId`. How can this be done?

Comment: what I actually did in my view is that when the document is first created then the id that I get is put in the model attribute, This attribute value (document id) is put as a hidden field value in the form which will be submitted. Now, as it is a part of the form, I should be getting the document_id but the problem is I am unable to get it i.e. null is returned.